# Python pandas DataFrame column insert call

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, insert

### I  have a simple txt file and I am reading it as follows:

```
data=pd.read_csv("data1.txt",sep=',', header = None)
data.columns=['X1', 'Y']
```

when I print this I get:-

```
       X1        Y
0      6.1101  17.5920
1      5.5277   9.1302
2      8.5186  13.6620
3      7.0032  11.8540
4      5.8598   6.8233
```

Now I want to insert a Column X0 in front of X1 ( to its left) and give this column a value of 1.so I added this code:-

```
data = data.insert(0,'X0',1)    
print(type(data))
print(len(data))
```

But I get the following error message:-

```
<class 'NoneType'>
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

The question is , is my data.insert correct?. why is that type of the dataframe coming as NoneType. what am I doing wrong here?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `insert` which acts in place, you can use `assign`

```
data = data.assign(X0=1)[['X0'] + data.columns.tolist()]
print(data)

   X0      X1        Y
0   1  6.1101  17.5920
1   1  5.5277   9.1302
2   1  8.5186  13.6620
3   1  7.0032  11.8540
4   1  5.8598   6.8233
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot assign [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) to new `DataFrame`, because it works `inplace`:

```
data.insert(0,'X0',1) 
print (data)
   X0      X1        Y
0   1  6.1101  17.5920
1   1  5.5277   9.1302
2   1  8.5186  13.6620
3   1  7.0032  11.8540
4   1  5.8598   6.8233
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes it worked. I am still an entry level with Pandas. appreciate your help.

Comment: I wish the doc had explicitly mentioned it.

Comment: Yes, I was surprised too - also I check it in docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#column-selection-addition-deletion) - `In [67]:`